# How would I loop the triangles/improve my code? (Nested triangle turtle)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I am currently learning python with The Open University, I have created some code to draw a set of nested triangles decreasing in size every time they are drawn.

I am asked to incorporate two loops to achieve this, but silly me has done it in one.

How would I achieve the two loop goal whilst achieving the same result?

```
>>> from turtle import *
>>> trisize = 80
>>> for triangles in range(1, 5):
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    trisize - 20
    penup()
    forward(10)
    left(90)
    forward(5)
    right(90)
    pendown()
    trisize = trisize - 20
```

My expected result is four triangles nested inside of each other, I achieve this but without using two loops.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, thank you to anyone who is currently trying to answer but hasn't commented yet. Here's my solution for anyone that needs it.

```
while trisize >= 20:
    for sides in range(1, 4):
        forward(trisize)
        left(120)
    penup()
    forward(10)
    left(90)
    forward(5)
    right(90)
    pendown()
    trisize = trisize - 20
```